# What to do on SyntaxError?

Tags: javascript

I had a problem in Visual Studio Code while programming my Discord bot and I don't know what to do here. Would be nice if you could help me.

Code: `bot.on('message', _message =>( let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");`

What comes out `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Comment: From your line of code you are missing two closing parenthesis, you should write `bot.on('message', _message =>( let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ")));`

Answer (score 0):

A [syntax error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_error) means your code is not valid JavaScript.
The `Unexpected identifier` roughly means "While parsing this code, I saw an identifier that I didn't expect. This cannot be valid JavaScript." An identifier is a type of [*lexical token*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis#Token) that serves as a symbol to identify a variable, function, constant, ... (in your example: `bot`, `on`, `_message`, `args`, ...).

The most common culprit among beginners is probably a typo related to brackets. Your code example looks incomplete. It is always good practice when learning to try to think about what an error means instead of immediately looking for anything that might be wrong (or about why a parser can't just say "hey, missing 2 brackets here"). These errors are trying to help you.